# Blank screen after installation

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I have installed Sonarqube with this howto: http://dev.mamikon.net/installing-sonarqube-on-ubuntu/. Also i have done all optional steps there.

But now, if i'm starting Sonarqube, a Browsertab with localhost:9000 results into a blank screen.

The sonar.log says: http://pastebin.com/AZVZp0i2

The web.log says: http://pastebin.com/kAAHa8B3

The mysql service is running: http://pastebin.com/dvFRMFRE

and also the database "sonar" exists and is healthy: http://pastebin.com/hdASb2bb

Maybe anyone knows how to locate the problem?

Comment: Anyone knows how to locate the problem?

Comment: Added outputs from service status and mysql status

Answer (score 0):

Please add/append the value of sonar.web.context to http://localhost:9000/{sonar.web.context}